# Minted package does not recognize class object names

Tags: minted

I'm using `minted` to format some C++ code and I realized that it does not color the class objects with the same color that it colors the class name, and to fix that I've created the `objectcolor` myself (but there's has to be a more elegant way of achieving this); check line 24 and 28.

Also, please check line 7 since I had to write `\color{black}` to make the `Display` word to appear black, otherwise it is colored magenta and I do not know why.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[c++]{manni}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codebackground}{RGB}{240, 240, 235}
\definecolor{objectcolor}{RGB}{0, 171, 135}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}
    [
    bgcolor=codebackground,
    fontsize=\small,
    linenos = true,
    escapeinside=||,
    mathescape=true
    ]{c++}
    # include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Point2D {
    public:
    void Set(int dx, int dy);
    void |\color{black}|Display();
    private:
    int mX;
    int mY;
    };

    void Point2D::Set(int dx, int dy) {
    mX = dx;
    mY = dy;
    }

    void Point2D::Display() {
    cout << "X: " << mX << ", Y: " << mY << endl;
    }


    int main() {
    Point2D point;
    point.Set(10,5);
    point.Display();

    |\color{objectcolor}Point2D| point2;
    point2.Set(7,11);
    point2.Display();
    }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tokenization of the source code is done by the `pygmentize` tool and can't be changed from within LaTeX. If you think this is a bug or a missing feature, you 'd have to [file an issue](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/) on the Pygments bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the link, already posted an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1525/c-object-names-highlight)